# When should I use $ref versus the object id in Open API

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm working on a schema in OpenAPI with Swagger, and I'm not sure if I'm misusing the `$ref` element. I have a `User` model and a `Project` model, similar to something like

```
User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
        name:
          type: string
        ...
Project:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        user_id:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/User"
        ...
```

I don't see much in the Open API Spec documentation as to what the `$ref` element is specifically, but in the JSON Schema documentation—of which Open API extends the `$ref` element—I've found the following description of the item:

> The easiest way to describe $ref is that it gets logically replaced with the thing that it points to.

In the case above, I just want to refer to the user who posted a project. It seems unnecessary to essentially include all of the information about the User in the Project model if that is what it's doing. Would it be better practice to just have a `string` element of the uuid of the `user_id`? Or is it correct as is? Is it more common to name the field `user` rather than `user_id` if that is the case?

**Edit**:
I realize the heart of what was bothering me is if there were to be recursive references. If a User has an array of `$ref` to Projects, but also a Project has an array of `$ref` to Users, the replacement (if that's what it's doing) would infinitely embed each model in the other. I assume this wouldn't happen in practice, assuming that a `$ref` is just a pointer to the Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example it might make sense to extract the `userId` definition into its own schema (assuming it is the `userId` only that appears, not an entire `User` object), then it is clearer what's going on:

```
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/userId'
        name:
          type: string
        ...
    Project:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        user_id:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/userId"
        ...
    userId:
      type: string
      format: uuid
```

But there is nothing stopping you creating a direct `$ref` to `#/components/schemas/User/properties/id` instead, as long as what is pointed to is a valid OpenAPI schemaObject.

Circular references are allowed by the JSON Reference and OpenAPI specifications, so your analogy of a pointer is a sound one.